# Getting a UIButton to send commands to another View Controller

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uibutton

Question.. 
I'm currently making a conversion app. I have for the first tab where the information is entered. Views 2 and 3 are where the information from view 1. I'm having an issue.. I'm not sure how to send the information from view 1 to view 2 and 3.

I've looked at examples.. but I'm still not quite grasping the idea of it. any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of thinking in terms of sending information between views, create a "model object" that contains all the data that is shared between views, and let controller classes take care of updating the views when the model is changed.

Also, take a look at the documentation for `NSNotificationCenter` for a way to "broadcast" data updates throughout your app.

Comment: I know this is going to make me sound stupid.. but i've been looking up how to make a "model object" and I'm still not understanding.. 

The questions i have left.. are: where do I store the model object..
I put every object I have for the 2 views in the model object?
Do I put the calculations in the model object as well?
I've never used a model object and I'm very new to coding.. I'm just not quite grasping the idea of this 
I like the idea of the model object better than the NSNotificationCenter

Thanks in advance!!